# Conditions to be careful of while using parallel streams

Tags: java, java-stream

What condition is required to use parallel streams in java 8?
Can we use it in all cases or could it cause some issues in some cases, or should we ensure something before using it?

Comment: A good question to think around. Not the right forum to ask such a broad question. You might want to search around first and then boil it down to a specific problem if you discover any.

Comment: You are expected to do research prior posting questions here. Like: using a search engine. Reading existing documentation, like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html ...

Comment: @Naman: I agree. Sadly, StackOverflow users don’t like simple questions that require a complex answer and vote to close as too broad or need more focus. This is a valid question, IMHO.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis As written above: this community also expects users to do prior research. Which isn't exactly showing here. And that the OP doesn't react to any of the comments, or even to the answer given ... doesn't help with the sentiment that this is a rather bad question.

Comment: Parallel processing comes at a cost. You have to split the source into multiple chunks, you have to handover these chunks to several workers and if youre doing an aggregation, you have to wait for the local aggregations to finish and finally combine these local aggregations into the final result one.

Only use it if your input data is big and is safe to be processed out of order. Also, read the docs of each operation carefully. While most of these docs should be taken care about even in non-parallel, in parallel they could break your neck (e.g. stateful filter-functions)

Comment: If you understand how fork-join works, you already can think of some operations where splitting the work wil not cause much gains (sorted,distinct,..). Also take into account the data set size vs overhead, data sructure (arrayList vs linkedList), etc.
So definitely not always use parallelStream. In a small business application, it will often do more harm than good.

Comment: side-effects; but generally this is too broad of a question. Did you go through the official documentation?

Answer (score 1):

The very first thing to understand: the key difference isn't about sequential or parallel **streams**.

**Streams** are just one specific concept in java designed for expressing data processing in neat, concise ways. Meaning: you can do sequential or parallel processing completely independent of streams.

Which leads to: the real question is if the **problem** you intend to solve allows for parallel processing. Many do, others do not. For example: there might be situations where you **absolutely** have to process "events" in the order they occurred. Then processing a "stream" of such "events in parallel is an absolute no-go. Because parallel always means: losing control over the order of processing.

Beyond that, there is another aspect: performance!

Keep in mind: parallel processing is a trade-off. You are willing to invest **more** CPU resources (also: code complexity) in order to compute some result *earlier*. Now: sometimes that trade-off is just not worth it. When you measure sequential vs parallel stream processing, you will find that (depending on many aspects): *setting* up the parallel stream itself is a pretty expensive operation. Meaning: if your task is to sort 5 objects, then doing that sequentially will always be faster compared to doing it in parallel. Because the sequential sort will long be done before the parallel code actually gets to doing the sorting!